# Using swagger in asp.net core RC2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-1.0, swashbuckle

I'm migrating a project from ASP.NET RC1 to RC2 but some packages are not working. VS is complaining about being unable to resolve them. What are the correct packages/versions to add

```
  "Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Below is the entire project.json file (in case something is missing). The last 3 packages fail with the same error (`The dependency XXX >= YYY could not be resolved`)

`{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "RestSharp": "105.2.3",
    "Flurl.Http": "0.7.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-3002702",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8",
        "portable-net4+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with .net 4.5. Check this project.json

```
{
   "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-beta9",
        "Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-beta9"
},

"tools": {
       "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
         "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
         "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
       }
},

"frameworks": {
       "net452": { }
},

"buildOptions": {
      "emitEntryPoint": true,
      "preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
    ]
 },

 "scripts": {
   "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
 }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'm still getting the errors on the swagger packages. The first package is also giving an error. Maybe it is another problem all together.

Comment: It worked after I added a NuGet.Config file to the project.

Comment: It don't work anymore with RTM version. I have this exception : `Could not load type Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions` on `AddSwaggerGen` extension method. You have to use the `6.0.0-beta901` version if you target `net452`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix rc1 and and rc2 packages in your project json. If you need to use swagger in your project, they have released new version for .net core rc2.

Update,
"Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-rc1-final"

to,
"Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-beta9",
"Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-beta9"

Comment: I'm having getting `    Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen (>= 6.0.0-beta9)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.`
`    Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi (>= 6.0.0-beta9)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'` with the update